# How can complement of degree apply at: 他喝酒喝得睡着了。 弟弟高兴得跳了起来。

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

When introduced 得 to my student, I followed the grammar book 100%: It's "complement of degree".  But when we bumped into these two sentences, should I still insist "complement of degree"? What kind of degree is 睡着了 and 跳了起来 ?  How to best explain to my students?

Comment: 高兴得（到了一个程度以至于）跳了起来

Comment: Do you mean 没有跳了起来 is less than 跳了起来 in degree sense?  What is the standard in degree?   We understand 很 is more that without 很 in degree sense, 极了 is higher, ... etc. But what kind of action can reveal the "degree", especially for people who don't like to show their emotion through actions.

Comment: Should Stephen Hawking "jumped" up to show he is is extremely excited degree?

Comment: please see my other answer where I discussed why the 'lower' degree is not common in any language https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38982/25227

Comment: I don't think many people will jump when they are happy. "Jumping" is a kind of conventional exaggeration that might happen in cartoons. Stephen Hawking can say that he is so happy that he jumped up, where the exaggeration is even more dramatic and vivid. These conventional exaggerations are sort of fixed, but I am not sure where to find a comprehensive list of them. 高兴得跳起来，高兴得手舞足蹈，高兴得哭了出来might be the only few commonly bound with 高兴。 Or, if a person really did something unusual, you can just describe it e.g. 高兴得开了一瓶珍藏的陈年红酒 which is not an exaggeration.

Comment: Another thing is that there is no point to compare the degrees of exaggerations. So I don't know which one is happier: 跳了起来 or 手舞足蹈.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdbg.net is not always a font of cutting edge accuracy, but they write about 得：

> structural particle: used after a verb (or adjective as main verb),
> linking it to following phrase indicating effect, degree, possibility
> etc (I would 得 definitely add at least: manner)

```
1. 他喝了酒。
   He drank.

2. 他睡着了。
   He slept.
```

Now try to show that 2. is somehow related to 1.

```
3. 他喝酒 （他）喝得（他）睡着了。
   He drank, (so much) that he fell asleep. (Sounds like me!)
   He drank until he fell asleep. (Sounds like me!)
```

Your knowledge tells you that drinking a small or even moderate amount of alcohol will not cause sleep.

The *assumption* is therefore, he overdid it, as River wrote: "到了一个程度以至于"

'fall asleep' was the effect of his drinking. In as much as he probably did not drink anymore *after* he was asleep, you may surmise that this represents, after a fashion, the (large) amount and therefore "the degree" of his drinking, but really sleep is the result or effect of 他喝太多而睡着了。 .

4. 弟弟高兴了。
   My little brother (was/is) happy.

5.弟弟跳了起来。
My little brother jumped for joy.

Now try to show that 5. is somehow related to 4.

How happy was your little brother?
你的弟弟有多高兴？
My little brother was (so) happy that he jumped for joy.
弟弟高兴得（他）跳了起来。
He was 'jump-for-joy' happy.

In my opinion, 'jump-for-joy' represents the effect his happiness had on him, not its degree. A scientific analysis of the degree of happiness would be fraught.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Obviously, I have been wrong all the time because I thought 得 only functioned with complement of degree, that's why I rendered the question in the first place.  I especially like your adding of "manner", perfect.  If using one term to include all the possibilities of complements, can we use "result" because when explaining to students, it's so difficult to list "all" of them?  Your adding "manner" is itself a perfect example of how difficult to list all.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to Chinese dictionary,when "得" is used after a verb or an adjective word, the complement can not only discribe the degree,but also mean the result.\

> 得（de）：用在动词或形容词后面，连接表示结果或程度的补语。————《现代汉语词典》 （第六版）

(Used behind a verb or an adjective word, connect to the complement that shows the result or degree._____from.Morden Chinese Dictionary 6th edition)
Some example:
"我跑得喘不过气。" ==>"I run out of breath."
"Out of breath" is the result of "run".

Answer (score 0):

Compare to the ***so... that*** structure.

1. so drunk that he falls asleep.
2. so happy that he jumps up.

Is it clear enough.?

So, basically degree complement is '***subjective***' and result complement is '***objective***'.

Comment: My question is simple:   how can "睡着了" and "跳了起来" be classified as "degree", not "result" after an action/event semantically?  Anybody cares to answer?  Your answer exactly emphasizing the "result" (that.... this happened) side not the "degree" side.  "degree" by nature is "levels after comparison" implied.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 The degree is implied. It's very subjective. Something can make you jump but may not make others do the same. The 'happiness' surpasses certain extent/degree that would make him jump. Does it make sense?

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 It's one's inner "auto calculation". There isn't a definite degree that works for everyone in this case.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 Usually, the resultative complement has a direct effect to the action.  E. g.  找到, where 到 is the result of 找. 到 is a direct result of 找.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 Compare 找烦了 to 找到.  烦了 is degree complement, whilst 到 is resultative complement. 找烦了 denotes one tries to find something but can't find it anywhere, at some point it surpasses his tolerance and becomes annoyed.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 So, basically degree complement is 'subjective' and result complement is 'objective'.

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately, your examples are all without 得，and my argument is based on 得 as "degree" complement.  I am still confused at 找得烦了 and 找得躺在地上 should both be interpreted as "degree" complement as both are subjective.

Comment: @JamesLiu刘老师 得 is an auxiliary word to facilitate. 找烦了 and 找得烦了 means the same thing. 得 is used to engage a complement either resultative or degree. So, 得 has nothing to do with your issue.